# Ashes : How do you play with 4 player?

Tags: ashes

So i've bought ASHES: Rise of the Phoenix born. I've played it with 3 of my friends which made a 4 player game with 4 pre-made Decks. Sadly the rules (at least in french) doesn't cover how it's supposedly played, half of the decks we had were designed for single play (Noah in particular, he's able to lock an opponnent but if there's a threat on the side he's likely to die first. In a lesser extent Meorin, with only 3 beasts couldn't really handle 3 turn of abuse on her beasts). So how is it done? Is it 2 players against 2 others? Is it that we should draft to even the odds?

Also, I really liked this game, but playing defensively is immensively hard to punish with 3 other players, it forces a stalemate that no one can break without dying, any tips to prevent that ever again?

Sorry for the long post, it might be hard to read, english is somehow not that easy for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had an answer from Isaac Vegas. This game is competitively based on one versus one, for 4 players play, it's better to make 2 1v1 battle, then a 1v1 battle for losers and one for winners.

Based on further play with friends, we discovered that 2v2 is quite balanced in most cases, and 1v1v1 works quite swiftly.

To prevent stalemates, what is advised is taking risks. Forcing others to attack by fragmenting your forces will incite them to strike you BUT, one will react more strongly than the others so it's supposedly the first to react that'll be maimed.